# I received a $150 check from Wells Fargo. I did have an account that was closed out of the blue for no reason. Are they trying to get out a lawsuit?

Tags: united-states, checking-account

I received a $150 check from Wells Fargo that was sent by federal express overnight. I did have an account years ago that was closed out of the blue for no reason. They said it was suspected fraud however, it was the same weekly paycheck that I had deposited for over 5 months. Next thing i knew I was having holds placed on my account and fees were placed on returned ach drafts for my bills. almost $900 of fees over 2 months. I tried to get them to understand that they were doing me wrong, but I was told it was a random computer choice and they had no control over which checks were held. I tried to get my money back for the fees, but they refused stating that it was my responsibility to make sure the check cleared before spending it. No deposited check had ever been returned for any reason.  Now I am holding a check stating that if I cash it, they have no further obligation to me. Should I peruse this further or just cash the check? Are they trying to get out a lawsuit?

Comment: Bit of a contradiction to say they closed your account "for no reason", and then in the next sentence to say what their reason was. I presume what you mean is, "for a reason that isn't valid". But to the relevant point, I think @keshlam's answer sums it up.

Answer (score 9):

You are asking us to read their minds. Can't do that.

But this certainly is structured as an offer of a token apology. Your choice is to accept it and not have to spend more time arguing about it, or to decline and continue trying to convince them and/or a court that they owe you more.

An offer is not an admission of wrongdoing, it's just a negotiation toward both parties being minimally unhappy. It does not imply that they think they'd lose in court, just that it would probably cost them more than this to continue arguing about it.

Your move. Only you can make that decision.